# Should I use 'true' or 'real' in "This is a {true/real} story..."?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

> This is a *true/real* story about a dog that has been adopted as a puppy.

What is preferred to use in this sentence? I think I could use both, but I'm not so sure :(

Comment: I would like non-fiction.

Answer (score 2):

**True** is the preferred word in this situation.  Many movies, novels and other pieces of literature say "based on a true story" and not "based on a real story".

Answer (score 0):

**True** is preferred.

But a common phrase is also *This story is based on* ***actual*** *events*.